# Why are some of the objects not getting removed in this .splice() and some are?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I'm using .splice() to remove objects from an array of objects containing a timestamp, based on whether the `userDates` contains either a matching timestamp or a timestamp within a range of 45 minutes before or after the object's timestamp. Essentially removing all objects with overlapping date values with the userDates array date values.

When you run this code, you'll notice that some of the objects get removed, but others don't.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jb2t3Lr9/1/ and code to reproduce the problem:

```
let userDates = ["2020-11-20T22:00:00.000Z","2020-11-20T23:00:00.000Z","2020-11-21T00:00:00.000Z","2020-11-21T01:00:00.000Z","2020-11-22T02:15:00.000Z","2020-11-22T03:15:00.000Z","2020-11-22T01:00:00.000Z","2020-11-22T00:00:00.000Z","2020-11-21T23:00:00.000Z","2020-12-13T22:00:00.000Z","2020-12-14T22:00:00.000Z","2020-12-15T22:00:00.000Z","2020-12-16T22:00:00.000Z","2020-12-13T23:00:00.000Z","2020-12-14T23:00:00.000Z","2020-11-21T20:00:00.000Z","2020-11-22T20:00:00.000Z","2020-11-22T19:00:00.000Z","2020-11-21T19:00:00.000Z"];

let datesToUpdate = [
  { sessionInterval: 50, dateTime: '2020-11-22T20:00:00.000Z' },
  { sessionInterval: 50, dateTime: '2020-11-21T20:00:00.000Z' },
  { sessionInterval: 50, dateTime: '2020-11-21T19:00:00.000Z' },
  { sessionInterval: 50, dateTime: '2020-11-22T19:00:00.000Z' },
  { sessionInterval: 50, dateTime: '2020-11-22T17:30:00.000Z' },
  { sessionInterval: 50, dateTime: '2020-11-21T17:00:00.000Z' }
];


function removeOverlappingDates(userDates, datesToUpdate) {
  const FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15 * 60 * 1000; // milliseconds
  datesToUpdate.forEach((toUpdate, index) => {
    userDates.forEach((date) => {
      let dateInMS = new Date("" + date).valueOf();
      const fifteenBefore = dateInMS - FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
      const thirtyBefore = dateInMS - FIFTEEN_MINUTES * 2;
      const fortyFiveBefore = dateInMS - FIFTEEN_MINUTES * 3;
      const fifteenAfter = dateInMS + FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
      const thirtyAfter = dateInMS + FIFTEEN_MINUTES * 2;
      const fortyFiveAfter = dateInMS + FIFTEEN_MINUTES * 3;
      let toUpdateInMS = new Date("" + toUpdate.dateTime).valueOf();
      if (
        toUpdateInMS == fifteenBefore ||
        toUpdateInMS == thirtyBefore ||
        toUpdateInMS == fortyFiveBefore ||
        toUpdateInMS == fifteenAfter ||
        toUpdateInMS == thirtyAfter ||
        toUpdateInMS == fortyFiveAfter ||
        toUpdateInMS == dateInMS
      ) {
        datesToUpdate.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  });

  return datesToUpdate;
}

console.log("datesToUpdate 1", datesToUpdate);
datesToUpdate = removeOverlappingDates(userDates, datesToUpdate);
console.log("datesToUpdate 2", datesToUpdate);
```

What's even stranger to me is that if I just compare to arrays of datetime values against each other (with the same datetime values as the array of objects contains), then everything gets removed properly. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rc1mvzLq/

Comment: Do not modify a collection you're currently iterating over (or at least only if you really know what you're doing) -> `datesToUpate.forEach((toUpdate, index) => { /*...*/ datesToUpdate.splice(index, 1) })`; What happens with the element at index `2` if you remove the element at index `1`?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.filter()` or a `for` loop at start at the last element and go to the first

Comment: @Andreas, ohhhh, the index values change! So that's why even I tried collecting the indexes together into another array and after the loops, run another loop to splice datesToUpdate, it didn't work either... ahhh. Okay, I'll give another try.

Comment: You're not checking the range in your code, but exact values inside the mentioned range. Is this on purpuse or should the if actually be `if (toUpdateInMS >= fortyFiveBefore || toUpdateInMS <= fortyFiveAfter)`? Also as mentioned, you should copy the array and iterate over the array's copy because once you do the first splice the array indices shifted but the loop will never go back to index 1 if it was already on index 2. However that still won't work because you're relying on old indices, but will need to find the index of the new element.

Comment: *correction: `if (toUpdateInMS >= fortyFiveBefore && toUpdateInMS <= fortyFiveAfter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to write this with minimal new methods, but as mentioned in the comments, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is ideal for this use case.

First and foremost, **never change the array you're iterating over**. That causes behaviours that are hard to debug. However, a copy of the array in the beginning would not help you in this case because you're using `splice` to remove an element of the array in the middle of it which causes a bunch of elements to reindex.

For example if you have `[A,B,C,D,E]` and you remove the element at index `1`, you now have `[A,C,D,E,F]` and (since the iteration for that index is done) your index got incremented and is now `2` and you will never test value `C` in your logic. A few more situations like this one and you can see how multiple elements get left unchecked. The only way this can work is if two elements that need to get deleted are never next to one another.

To keep this simple and as close to your original logic as possible, what I advise is that you count how many elements you've deleted and offset the index by that amount. However also copy the array so that you don't mutate the one you're iterating over (NOTE: a shallow copy is enough, and you can simply use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new array with the **same** objects).

```js
function removeOverlappingDates(userDates, datesToUpdate) {
  const FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15 * 60 * 1000; // milliseconds
  const newDatesToUpdate = [...datesToUpdate];
  let deletedElementsCount = 0;
  datesToUpdate.forEach((toUpdate, index) => {
    // same code as before
      if (
        // check if this condition should maybe be toUpdateInMS >= fortyFiveBefore && toUpdateInMS <= fortyFiveAfter
      ) {
        const newIndex = index - deletedElementsCount;
        newDatesToUpdate.splice(newIndex, 1);
        deletedElementsCount = deletedElementsCount + 1;
      } 
    });
  });

  return newDatesToUpdate;
}
```

As a side note, there is a reason why the copy is the one I'm changing and that's because `datesToUpdate` is passed as a function argument. If the `datesToUpdate` array gets changed inside the function, it will remain changed after it. You shouldn't change argument objects (this includes arrays) inside functions unless you want it to remain like that. A function that does this it is considered to have [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) and this can also be hard to debug if not used cautiously. In your case there is no need to do side effects because you're returning the result.

Comment: Nice!! Thanks a lot! I was stuck with this for a while, and this is a way nicer implementation. I probably would have cloned through JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()). I tried keeping track of indexes, reversing them and iterating over the indexes to splice and return the cloned array (inspired by Andreas's comment), however, didn't quite get that to work either (probably because I should have also spliced from the end of the array of the reindexing would just reoccur). Thanks a lot! And you're right about the range as well.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to *push* successful elements to a new array rather than copying the array and splicing out fails. So the change is just `datesToUpdate.splice(index, 1)` to `newArray.push(datesToUpdate[index])`, which effectively emulates *filter*.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot simpler, but I wanted to keep the logic and structure as similar as it was before, and pushing would involve inverting a condition that I wasn't certain was correct in the first place. But I definitely agree push is a lot better and simpler.

Comment: An even simpler approach, that doesn't use filter and also works with mutating the collection, is a plain old `for` that iterates from the back. This wouldn't require any additional changes (like re-calculating the index,...)

Comment: Both the ways are useful for me to know and be aware of so I'm quite happy about both of you sharing your ideas, thank you!

Comment: @Andreas, do you mean something like this? ```for (var i = items.length-1; i > -1; i--) { items.splice(i, 1) }```

Comment: @robertfoenix Yes. If you now remove an element you only change the index of elements you've already visited.

Comment: @5ar, you mentioned to never change the array you're iterating over, however what if when the change does occur, you use ```break``` to get out of the loop? Though I guess that'd no longer be an 'iteration' from that point forward.

Comment: The "never" is more of a general guideline because doing something like that is an easy way to get errors in various edge cases even if you know what you're doing. Generally just avoid it by doing a shallow copy or writing your logic so that it does not require doing that. If you really want to do it my practice is to opt for a regular `for` loop so that I have explicit control over the index increment and end condition, but that's just my coding style. Btw, in `forEach` you use `return` and not `break` because you're in an inner function not a classical loop block

Comment: Yep, the for loop use in this case makes quite the sense it seems! I've also read it's faster too, so seems like little to nothing to lose to omit forEach for a regular for loop!

Comment: It's faster and slightly more memory efficient because you don't need to create a new function (the one you pass to `forEach` as an argument), and call it on every iteration (+ calling the next function of the iterator that enables `forEach`) - which triggers extra memory assignments and jumps in the machine code. However, all of that is usually inconsequential because you need to invoke that piece of code really frequently for it to have a performance impact, and `forEach` generally has an easier to read syntax for simple cases.

Comment: As a side note, for layers where I'm worried about the extra function memory impact (usually when constructing objects that are arrays in arrays of some large aggregate, or code that can be invoked multiple times per second), I often use the [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax as a compromise between `forEach` and a regular for loop

Comment: @robertfoenix _"It's faster and slightly more memory efficient..."_ - Don't think about these things until you have found an actual bottleneck in your code **with a profiler**.